# How to prove a complicated function is always non-positive for a given range?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, inequality

Given constant $a>0$ and $b \in (0,1)$. I believe a complicated function as below to be always non positive in the range of $x>0$ and $x\neq a$. However, I could not prove or disprove it generally.
$$f(x) = \frac{2(x^b-a^b)}{(x-a)^3} - \frac{b(x^{b-1}+a^{b-1})}{(x-a)^2} \leq 0$$

I tried to use [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xzt5dogrqg) and generate a dynamic plot w.r.t different $a$ and $b$ and it seems to be true.

I also calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$. This is obvious since the exponent of x is smaller in the numerator compared to the denominator.

Trivial cases: For $b=0$ and $b=1$ we can easily obtain $f(x)=0$. We can simplify the problem to prove the correctness of the following inequality $\frac{2(x^b-a^b)}{x-a} \leq b(x^{b-1}+a^{b-1})$, obtained from multiplying $(x-a)^2$ for both terms. We can show that this inequality is true for $b=\frac{1}{2}$, since $\frac{2}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}+a^{\frac{1}{2}}} \leq \frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}} + a^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$ by AM-HM. I was trying to use AM-HM to solve other case such as $b=\frac{1}{k}$ or $b=\frac{k-1}{k}$ for $k \geq 2 \in \mathbb{N}$ but I was not able to do so. I highly doubt, AM-HM is the way to go to solve this problem, but I want to solve some simpler case and see if I can find any more idea to proceed.

Comment: What is the common denominator.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah If you want, you can consider multiply $(x-a)$ in both numerator and denominator for the second term to make $(x-a)^3$ a common denominator. I am not sure if this answer your question.

Comment: Yes, but after you do that, you see that the denominator is negative when $x<a$ and positive when $x>a$, so you only have to prove that the same is true of the numerator.  This gives you a simpler function to work with.

Comment: @saulspatz I was thinking something similar at first and try to split into two different cases as you mentioned. However, some terms will be positive while others are negative, which makes showing the whole function non-positive is not as simple. Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to think about it further and see if I make any further progress.

Comment: @saulspatz I am new to stack exchange and I really appreciate your guidance. Thank you for your suggestion, I have removed the comment and edit the body of my question.

Comment: I don't see how to do it offhand, but I'm terrible at inequalities.  I hope that, now that you've improved the question, it will attract more attention.  I added the inequality tag, in hopes of attracting an expert.

Answer (score 1):

Proof sketch:

- In the case $a < x$, let $x = a / y$, and in the case $x > a$, let $x = a y$. You can verify that in both cases, the inequality reduces to
  $$
  \frac{2(y^b-1)}{(y - 1)^3} - \frac{b(y^{b-1}+1^{b-1})}{(y-1)^2} \leq 0.
  $$
  So we need only prove that the above is true for $y > 1$.
- Algebraically manipulate the above expression into
  $$
  \frac{y^{b/2} - y^{-b/2}}{b} \le \frac{y^{1-b/2} - y^{b/2 - 1}}{2-b}.
  $$
  The fact that $y > 1$ ensures you don't have to worry about multiplying by negative numbers.
- Show that $\sinh(x)/x$ is an increasing function. Use this fact, $\ln(y) > 0$, and $1-b/2 > b/2$ to conclude the above inequality is true.

Comment: Just wanna double check if you mean $x < a$ for the first portion.
Really appreciate the help. Thank you very much, your proof is brilliant and elegant.